# How to process several JavaRDDs all at once?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I had a large dataset of format `csv` and i need to perform some RDD operations on this dataset without using any DataFrames/Dataset API and SparkSQL.By achieving this, i loaded each column of data into separate JavaRDD.

Here is my Sample dataset:

```
id    name    address   rank
1001  john    NY        68
1002  kevin   NZ        72
1003  steve   WA        64
```

Here is the code i tried so far:

```
JavaRDD<String> diskfile = sc.textFile("/Users/hadoop/Downloads/a.csv");
JavaRDD<String> idRDD=diskfile.flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(",")[0]));
JavaRDD<String> nameRDD=diskfile.flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(",")[1]));
JavaRDD<String> addressRDD=diskfile.flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(",")[2]));
```

after this i applied `reduceByKey` on both `addressRDD` and `nameRDD`like this:

```
JavaPairRDD<String,Integer> addresspair=address.mapToPair( t -> new Tuple2 <String,Integer>(t,1)).reduceByKey((x, y) -> x + y);
JavaPairRDD<String,Integer> namepair=nameRDD.mapToPair( t -> new Tuple2 <String,Integer>(t,1)).reduceByKey((x, y) -> x + y);
```

**Problem:**

I applied soryByVale(swap the key -values) on addresspair and get one address value(`result`) which is occurred highest number of times. Now i need to return all required columns of csv file which contains address field as `result`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` like below.

```
JavaRDD<String> filteredData = diskfile.filter(add -> add.contains(result));
filteredData.foreach(data -> {
            System.out.println(data);
        });
```

Comment: thanks for response. its prints whole line i.e, data here. but my need is have to print only selected columns.

Comment: Which columns do you want to select?

Comment: id, address and rank columns

Comment: You should actually use Dataframe for operation around columns. For this case, to remove addrss string from line, you can use JavaRDD<String> filteredData = diskfile.filter(add -> add.contains(result)).map(line -> line.replace(","+result, ""));